# AJAX search form: how to trigger PHP query?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, search

I am new to AJAX, and I stumbled upon a small problem. I have a custom search field for pages within my database:

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_GET['fdf_search'])){
     $term_search = $_GET['fdf_search'];
     $fdf_pages = $mysqli_con->select("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `alias` LIKE '%".$term_search."%'");
}
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fdf-search").keyup(function() {
    // Assign $_GET['fdf-search'] to variable "searchKey" in js
    var searchKey = $('#fdf-search').val();
    if (searchKey == "") {
        //nothing
    }else{
        console.log('ajax called');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/fluidify/fdf-admin/functions/fdf_system_search.php",
            data: {
                search:searchKey
            },
            success: function(html){
                window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?fdf_search=" + searchKey + "");
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="fdf-search" class="fdf-search" type="text" placeholder="zoeken" name="fdf_search" value="">
    <input class="fdf-search" type="submit" value="Zoeken" name="fdf_submit_search">
</form>
```

When I type in any word, I want my AJAX to trigger the PHP query and find and return any result. Right now `window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?fdf_search=" + searchKey + "");` is changing the `GET` in my URL, but for some reason it does nothing.

All help is appreciated :)

EDIT: select(); class

```
public function select($query,$report = NULL){
    $result_array = array();
    $result_empty = false;
    $result = $this -> query($query);
    if($result !== false){
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            $result_array[] = $row;
        }
        return($result -> num_rows === 0) ? false : $result_array;
    }else{
        if($report === true){
            echo "error in query:";
            print_r($result);
            print_r($result_array);
            print_r($query);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"is changing the GET in my URL, but for some reason it does nothing"* - Those are two mutually exclusive things.  *All that line of code does* is modify the URL value.  If it's successfully doing that, then it's working.  Was there something else you wanted your code to do as well?

Comment: Well, i want to get new results from the PHP query. My `GET` variable is updating with the code I provided, but for some reason I don't get updated results from my PHP query.

Comment: it looks like your php code does not echo anything, plus your ajax's success function doesn't make use of the response (html), you need to echo something from php and use that inside your success function.

Comment: In your AJAX `success` function you're not doing anything with the `html` variable.  That would contain any content returned by the server.

Comment: you should give POST in  type: "GET", ajax call. because you are passing data as like in body

Comment: @David Ah yeah, forgot to mention that I tried some things for a while, where `html` keeps returning empty results. I am kinda stuck with everything from the `succes()` part on

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan the ajax request method is set to `GET` so he should be using `$_GET`.

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan What do you mean? The method is GET so I should be using GET right?

Comment: `search:searchKey` should be `fdf_search:searchKey`

Comment: @Saypontigohe Nope. in ajax call and php. $.ajax({ type: "GET",}) should be POST. And also in php $_POST['search']

Comment: @Saypontigohe: Honestly, there seems to be a lot wrong here.  You don't need to be changing the URL at all, not sure why you want to.  You're sending a parameter called `search` to the server, but looking for a parameter called `fdf_search` on the server.  The server-side code doesn't output anything.  The client-side code ignores any output anyway.  And to top it all off, you're also wide open to SQL injection and not checking for any errors on the server or the client.

Comment: @David Without a working script I don't bother to optimize for security yet, but I sure will do! About the parameters, if i change it to fdf_search, I only get 500 errors back. What is the first step to do now I am stuck?

Comment: @Saypontigohe: *"Without a working script I don't bother..."* - SQL injection isn't just a security vulnerability, it's also a very common source of errors.  That's like saying "I don't want to get this working until I get it working first."  As for the rest, you at least need to match up your parameter names.  Change `search:searchKey` to `fdf_search:searchKey`.  Also change your PHP code to actually output something (such as `echo json_encode($fdf_pages);`).  And in your client-side code, remove the line that changes the URL and do something with the `html` variable instead.

Comment: Thing is, the `html` is empty, so I cannot do anything with it. This is a problem on my side, since I don't understand stat much from the AJAX itself, hence why I am creating a basic thing like a search tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get results back you should output something from your php code like so :

```
 if(isset($_GET['fdf_search'])) {
     $term_search = $_GET['fdf_search'];
     $fdf_pages = $mysqli_con->select("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `alias` LIKE '%".$term_search."%'");
     //output the result
     echo json_encode($fdf_pages);
 }
```

and your ajax call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/fluidify/fdf-admin/functions/fdf_system_search.php?fdf_search=" + searchKey
}).done(function(json){
    //parse the ajax response
    search_result = JSON.parse(json);

    //do something with search_result ...

 });
```

Comment: your sql query was missing some quotes as well :)

Comment: I see, my bad! However, the real SQL was way longer, but I shortened it for readability :)

With the new ajax call i get 500 errors in my PHP file. Not sure why yet...

Comment: i'm sure `$mysqli_con->select()` is not a mysqli function, did you mean `$mysqli_con->query();`

Comment: select is a class. Inside the class i use query(); Everything but the ajax part is used in all my web projects, so that should not be the problem :)

Comment: what does the php debug console tell you ?

Comment: Nothing, only error I get is in the browser console, stating that there is an 500 error in Jquery:2 (which is the endless rule of code :)

Comment: The problem lays in the rule url: "/fluidify/fdf-admin/functions/fdf_system_search.php?fdf_search=" + searchKey, whereas the url cannot be found (at least, if i remove + searchKey, it gives no error)

Comment: actually the result of the query is a 500 error code which your web server sends back to you, it only means that there is something wrong with your php code that's why you should check your IDE's debug console output or your server error_log, it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Normally I would get errors in my error log on the server, but there isn't a single error rule.

Comment: if the url cannot be found you should get a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: True, but an URL within PHP/javascript could give 500 error. The 500 error only shows up in my console though, not on the page itself. Everything is still working fine

Comment: yes it should show on your console because Ajax sends a request then gives you the result of that request, if something went wrong on the back-end (your php code) then a 500 error code is displayed. or a 404 Not found if the url does not exist. (everything happens on your browser's console, it's how Ajax works )

Comment: Strange that I do not recieve any server error logs, nor error displays internally :(

Comment: if you are using apache on redhat based systems then you might want to do a `sudo cat /var/log/httpd/error_log`, and see if there are any errors.

Comment: can you share the code of `$mysqli_con->select()` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170908/discussion-between-xanadev-and-saypontigohe).

Comment: Of course! Updated my question! (This is the non-secured version. We work with prepared statements, but within complex projects, we have a habit to work with a simplified version of all systems)